# Where is the source XML for electronic payment transformations in Dynamics ax?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm trying to assist in creating a binary or xsl transformation for a company.  I have the destination schema and sample destination xml.  However, to write the transformation, I need to know what the source xml looks like.

I know nothing about AX, I'm just writing the transformation.  Where can I tell my Dynamics AX guy to find the source XML that I need for electronic payments in Dynamics AX 2012?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to generate an electronic payment rather than search for some location of source XML. That way you obtain an up to date file with data including all customizations in a particular Dynamics AX 2012 instance.

Please see a [Walkthrough: Configuring an outbound integration port for payments](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh446522.aspx) for details.

Or you can perform the following steps quick and dirty.

Export the XML style sheet for the payment format:

1. Open the AOT in Dynamics AX 2012, and then expand the **Resources** node.
2. Right-click **VendPayments_SEPACreditTransfer_xslt**, and then click **Open**.
3. Click **Export**.

Outbound integration port must be configured:

1. Click **System administration > Setup > Services and Application Integration Framework > Electronic payment services > Outbound ports for electronic payments**.
2. In the **Payment format** field, select **SEPACreditTransfer**.
3. In the **XSLT** field, select the XSLT file that you previously exported. For example, the location of the XSLT file might be **c:\AX\SEPA\SEPAVend.xsl**.
4. In the **Outbound folder** field, select the location where you want to save the payment files after they are transformed. For example, the location might be **c:\AX\SEPA**.
5. Click **Create ports**.

Payment generation itself is the following (see an elaboration [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh209199.aspx)):

1. Enter a vendor invoice, and then enter and settle a payment with the invoice.
2. **Journal voucher** form > **Functions** > **Generate the payment**

Invoke the following routine to generate output (or you can configure batch processing, as described at aforementioned walkthrough):

```
static void runAIFOutbound(Args _args)
{
    // populate queue
    new AifGateWaySendService().run();

    // process queue
    //new AifOutboundProcessingService().run();
}
```

Wait for the queue to be processed and check the target folder you had specified earlier.

Comment: Just to clarify, we have electronic payments up and running using SEPACreditTransfer stylesheet.  However, we need a custom payment format, thus we need a custom transformation.  Out of the box transforms will not work.  I need to write a new XSLT or binary transformation.  However, I don't know how to do that without knowing what the source looks like.